# ifelse/case_when with seemingly tricky strings in a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a mortality dataframe with a character vector (`rac`) that contains varying strings per row. These strings flag contributing causes of death. Sometimes these strings have an extra whitespace between them (see `id = 4, 5, 8`). Some times they have exactly 3 characters and at other times they have 4 characters. What I am trying to do is sweep through by row and create a new column that flags whether a particular cause of death is seen in rac or not. Here are the data.

```
tdf <- structure(list(id = 1:10, rac = c("I250", "K922 R628", 
"C259 T149 X599", "K729 C80  J80  N288", "X72  S019", "C189", 
"C259 A419 K746 N390", "C349 C787 C793 C795 F179 I10  J449", 
"C349 J449 R628", "F03  N189 R628")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Take `id = 8`, where I can easily create a flag called cause_c that notes when `C793` or `C795` are seen with something like this snippet.

```
causex <- c("\\bC793|\\bC795")
tdf %>%
  mutate(
    cause_C = case_when(
      str_detect(rac, causex) ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0)
  ) -> tdf
```

It seems to work but I would like to be able to sweep in instances where the vector only shows 3 digits, say `C79` and when this happens, `cause_C` should `= 1`. This is also a more efficient way to create the flags because then I don't have to spell out all possible versions of the code (C793, C794, C79, and so on), and because I have multiple causes to go through and flag some 16 likely causes of death. But if I try the following `id = 8` will end up as all 0s.

```
tdf %>%
  mutate(
    cause_C = case_when(
      str_sub(rac, 1, 3) == "C79" ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0)
  ) -> tdf
```

There is something I am missing with the ifelse()\case_when() solution and if anyone spots my mistake and the fix, I would be very appreciative! And oh, base-R, data.table(), dplyr(), all solutions are welcome because I would be happy to see the speed comparisons too given the dataframe is chewing up more than 1.5 gigs.

Thank you!

Ani

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `data.table`, would you consider splitting up the rows by diagnostic code, then use `grepl` to match to your vector of desired diagnoses?

```
library(data.table)

causex <- c("C793", "C795")

search_causex <- paste(causex, collapse = "|")

setDT(tdf, key = "rac")
tdf[, list(rac = unlist(strsplit(rac, " "))), by = id][
  , result := grepl(search_causex, rac)][
    result == TRUE]
```

If you want to search by fewer characters you could use this for search pattern:

```
search_causex <- "C79(.+)"
```

A `tidyverse` similar approach could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

tdf %>%
  separate_rows(rac, sep = " ") %>%
  filter(grepl(search_causex, rac) == TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift assistance @Ben. I will give these a whirl tomorrow and reply + check it as answered.